# How can i remove an active icon from the launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons

I have both Chrome and Firefox running (Chrome for work and Firefox for music). How can I remove the Firefox icon from the launcher as I keep clicking on it accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the unwanted icon and select "Unlock from Launcher".

Alternatively left click on icon, then hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and drag it to bottom of Launcher.